# Smarty get offset of array

Tags: arrays, smarty, offset, prestashop-1.6

I have some trouble in Prestashop 1.6 using Smarty.

I have an array, but its offset are not reset for each product.

So for the first product, with attribute it has offset 1,2,3,4 Then for the next product it has offset 5,6,7,8 etc.

I have that kind of array

```
$combinations   Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (4)
  5 => Array (14)
    attributes_values => Array (1)
      1 => "S"
    attributes => Array (1)
      0 => 1
    price => 0
    specific_price => Array (0)
    ecotax => 0
    weight => 0
    quantity => 20
    reference => ""
    unit_impact => 0
    minimal_quantity => "1"
    date_formatted => ""
    available_date => ""
    id_image => -1
    list => "'1'"
  6 => Array (14)
```

I try to go through this array but it does not work when I put empty offset (it is inside a foreach)

```
{$combinations[]['quantity']}
```

How can I tell him to go through the first iteration, and then in the second automatically ?

This return to me the following errors.

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in /htdocs/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d code on line 584

I can not tell it which offset to use, because for each product it goes up and is not reset to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it, `current` return the first value of an array

```
{$combination = current($combinations)}
{$combination['quantity']}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to access directly to the table.  With no loop. But I dont Know the first key because it change for each product page.

Comment: try `{$combinations[0]['quantity']}`

Comment: It does not wor because 0 is not always the first key. What I need to find is the first key of a given array

Comment: Pardon me asking, but why no loop? It seems to be a perfect solution for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @UnLoCo answer, if you need these keys 1,2 ... 7,8

```
{foreach from=$array key=key item=value}
    {$key} => {$value}
{/foreach}
```

or

```
{foreach $array $key=>$value} {* like PHP style *}
        {$key} => {$value}
{/foreach}
```

Also Smarty docs may help you http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Comment: What I need to find is the first key of a given array with no loop.  Is it possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448838/get-first-smarty-array-element  in your case it will be {assign var=first value = $combinations|@key}
{$combinations.$first.content}